# Facing issue and not able to load data on live app

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

I am facing a weird issue on live app and getting multiple reviews on play store regarding this issue.

**Problem statement -**
Lets suppose user has installed version of v1.7application and there is new update on play store. Once user update the app to v1.8 (Not sure its manual update or automatic background update) then loader is continuously showing on application and error message is showing that is we shown in case of API failure.

We tried same scenario to reproduce at our end but not able to reproduce this issue.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me what is causing here
Multiple users are facing this issue, and after clear cache/storage it starts working again on v1.8